# Does doing a git commit and push save the files locally too?

Tags: git

So if I do a git push and commit, does the file get saved to my local hdd (like on my computer)?

I wonder because I got a grade on a project saying some things weren't working. They were for me though, so it seems even though I pushed right before submission, the files on the hdd were not updated, so the modifications were not in the submission.

Comment: When you got push and commit you commit the changes to your online repository. In order to get the files onto another computer from your repository you need to pull.

Answer (score 4):

`git commit` will create a commit object stored into your local git repository (which is usually is `.git`).  It will also update the ref that is your local branch to point to the new commit.

`git push` will attempt to cause a remote repository's branch to match your local branch.  It does this by sending all relevant commits that the remote doesn't already have.  The remote's branch will then point to the same commit that your local branch points.

Answer (score 2):

Git push, commit and does everything on files which are saved already.
You can't push file which in during editing.

So git doesn't save files.